# Select preceding elements until I find an element to stop on (XSLT 1.0)

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

I want to select the a elements that precede bird until I hit dog, but not select the bird or dog. And, I don't know what the elements are. They could be different than in the sample XML.  And, I would like to do it in the select of a variable.

Input XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<root>
  <a>cat</a>
  <a>dog</a>
  <a>dog</a>
  <a>cat</a>
  <a>snake</a>
  <a>cat</a>
  <a>cat</a>
  <a>bird</a>
  <a>dog</a>
  <a>cat</a>
</root>
```

Desired Output XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<root>
  <a>cat</a>
  <a>snake</a>
  <a>cat</a>
  <a>cat</a>
</root>
```

XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl"
>
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:variable name="nodes">
      <xsl:copy-of select="//a"/>
    </xsl:variable>

    <xsl:variable name="nodeList" select="msxsl:node-set($nodes)"/>

    <!-- I want to select the a elements that precede bird until I hit dog, but not select the bird or dog. 
          And, I don't know what the elements are. They could be different than in the sample XML. 
          And, I want to do it in the select of the variable below.
    -->
    <xsl:variable name="subsetOfNodeList" select="$nodeList/a[.='bird']/preceding-sibling::a[. >> $nodeList/a[.='bird']/preceding-sibling::a[.='dog'][1]]"/>

    <xsl:template match="root">
      <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:copy-of select="$subsetOfNodeList"/>
      </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template> 

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Your title says XSLT 1.0, however you have tagged the question as XSLT 1.0 as well and XSLT 2.0 and in your sample you use the `>>` operator that does not exist in XSLT 1.0. So you need to clarify which version you want to use.

Comment: Hi Martin,  My mistake.  It's Mircosoft Version 1.0.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Given XSLT 1 I think you can select the preceding-siblings of the `bird` and intersect (remember intersection of node-sets `n1` and `n2` is done with `$n1[count(. | $n2) = count($n2)]`) them with anything following the `dog`, here is an example that additionally uses a key to identify what follows the `dog`:

```
  <xsl:key name="fol" match="a[not(. = 'dog')]" use="generate-id(preceding-sibling::a[. = 'dog'][1])"/>

  <xsl:template match="root">
      <xsl:variable name="bird" select="a[. = 'bird']"/>
      <xsl:variable name="prec-dog" select="$bird/preceding-sibling::a[. = 'dog'][1]"/>
      <xsl:variable name="fol-dog" select="key('fol', generate-id($prec-dog))"/>
      <xsl:variable name="prec-siblings" select="$bird/preceding-sibling::a[not(. = 'dog')]"/>
      <xsl:variable name="intersect" select="$prec-siblings[count((. | $fol-dog)) = count($fol-dog)]"/>
      <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:copy-of select="$intersect"/>
      </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
```

At https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/eiQZDbr/2 for the input

```
<root>
  <a id="c1">cat</a>
  <a id="d1">dog</a>
  <a id="d2">dog</a>
  <a id="c3">cat</a>
  <a id="s1">snake</a>
  <a id="c4">cat</a>
  <a id="c5">cat</a>
  <a>bird</a>
  <a>dog</a>
  <a>cat</a>
</root>
```

I get the result

```
<root>
  <a id="c3">cat</a>
  <a id="s1">snake</a>
  <a id="c4">cat</a>
  <a id="c5">cat</a>
</root>
```

Comment: Hi Martin, Thanks for the answer.  What I'm really looking for is a way to do what I want in the select of the subsetOfNodeList variable in XSLT 1.0.  From what I gather now, the << and >> operators are only available in 2.0.  Is there another operator I can use in 1.0 that is equivalent?  I've been trying to do the intersect that you mentioned.  But, have not worked it out yet.

Comment: I understood that you want to use a variable and have a `select` expression but `<xsl:variable name="intersect" select="$prec-siblings[count((. | $fol-dog)) = count($fol-dog)]"/>` does that (even if I have used a different variable name). I don't see any need for or any reason for your result tree fragment given that there you only copy input nodes and then turn them into a node-set again, in that case it suffices to directly use the input nodes and use a node set intersection.

Comment: I made up the sample data.  So, I could load it into my $nodeList variable and from that zero in on my specific question.  Which is selecting nodes before or after another node in document order.  But, from what I am gathering << and >> are 2.0 only.  And, there is nothing like it for 1.0.  And, no simple work around thus far.  I want to be able to do what I am doing in the select of the subsetOfNodeList variable.

Comment: The operators `>>` and `<<` were indeed introduced in XPath 2 and that way also in XSLT 2. As for the concrete sample data, my answer selects the intersection of the preceding siblings of  `bird` element with the following siblings of the `dog` element and that way selects the nodes between those two elements in document order.

Comment: Okay Martin.  Thanks for you help.  I appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

One of possible solutions is to make the "initial" call of a dedicated
template (let's call it **print**), passing it the last element to be
printed, i.e. the first preceding sibling of *bird* element (I assume
such a *bird* element is only one).

This template:

- Checks whether the argument passed has content other than
  *dog* (actually a condition to do anything). If this is the case then:

  - Make a recursive call to itself, passing it the first preceding
    sibling of the argument element.
  - Print the element passed as the argument.

So the whole script can look like below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:transform version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />

  <xsl:template name="print">
    <xsl:param name="xx"/>
    <xsl:if test="$xx/text() != 'dog'">
      <xsl:call-template name="print">
        <xsl:with-param name="xx" select="$xx/preceding-sibling::*[1]"/>
      </xsl:call-template>
      <xsl:copy-of select="$xx"/>
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="root">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:call-template name="print">
        <xsl:with-param name="xx" select="a[text() = 'bird']/preceding-sibling::*[1]"/>
      </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```

For a working example see http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/gWcDMet

Comment: Hi Valdi_Bo, Thanks for the answer.  What I'm really looking for is a way to do what I want in the select of the subsetOfNodeList variable in XSLT 1.0.  From what I gather now, the << and >> operators are only available in 2.0.  Is there another operator I can use in 1.0 that is equivalent?

Comment: Change the XSLT version to 2.0, then you will have "<<" and ">>" operators avaialble and will be able to make any possible use of them.

Comment: Unfortunately, that can't be done.  My code is just a small cog in a large wheel.  I have no say in it.  Thanks again for you input.